# Full Windows 7 student edition UK

Tags: windows-7, license

What is the cheapest way to buy full Windows 7 (any flavour) for a UK student? I am building a new PC, so I don't have any old versions to upgrade from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link no longer is valid for windows 7, the offer has expired.

Depending on which institution you go to and what course you are doing you may be able to get windows 7 for FREE. Infact you can get lots of microsoft for free, except office, which is cheap if you do use the above link.

The way to get windows for free and things like visual studi etc is with MSDN AA.
The MSDN Academic Alliance.

Search here to see if you qualify: http://www.msdnaa.net/search/schoolsearchIntl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's UK education page has some links to companies they claim offer educational discounts: http://www.microsoft.com/uk/education/studentoffer/default.aspx

I won't guarantee that this is the cheapest, but it's a good starting point, at least.